# What is the earliest source for the Tanach order in our Tanachs?

Tags: tanach

What is the earliest source for the Tanach order?

The idea that the order of books in the hebrew bible is first the 5 books of moses, then the prophets, then the writings?

I'm referring exclusively to the order of T-N-K, not the order of the books within those sections.

Comment: @DoubleAA - note that sometimes K come before N, as in the 10 Psukim of Malchios - see IkarTY on Mishna 4:6 in Rosh Hashono. (Just a starting data point.)

Comment: @DannySchoemann The Gemara there takes it for granted that it’s T-N-K and therefore has to give alternative reasons why Kesuvim are upgraded.

Comment: Perhaps the earliest source is the Gemara, Bava Bathra 14b, which first lists the order of the Prophets and then the order of the Writings. But maybe this doesn't mean to teach us the Prophets comes before the Writings, maybe it has only come to teach us the order of the books in each category.

Comment: For quick reference, Rambam records the order of the Tanakh in Hilchoth Mezuzah uTefillin uSefer Torah, 7:16.

Comment: Looks like many comments have been deleted. Was it you @DoubleAA that deleted them?  IIRC Ezra tried to argue something about TNK being in order of the writings.. But it's not so because e.g. assumnig that Ezra=Malachi,  Psalms and Malachi are not in order in Tanach. And i think people agreed that Ezra was incorrect re that one..

Comment: @barlop wasn't me. I still don't understand what other order you'd expect them to be in.

Comment: Also, in case this causes any confusion, this question got closed  but got voted to be reopened.